# Generating textual representation of directory contents

Tags: directory, plaintext, representation

I'm looking for a script to generate the graphical-ish textual representations of directory structures that you see around.  Something that I can run like this:

```
james@computer:/.../basedir$ listdir .
basedir
|-firstsubdir
| |-file
| `-subsubdir
|   |-file1
|   |-file2
|   |-file3
|   `-file4
`-secondsubdir

james@computer:/.../basedir$
```

Presumably an established script exists?  Must I write it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tree` (on Windows as well as Linux - might require a `apt-get install tree` or similar on Linux).

Type `tree /?` (windows) or `man tree` for the command line options.

Comment: There we go!  Works like a charm.  Now why did that not appear in my diligent Google searching?

Comment: For those just discovering `tree`, two useful flags are `-d` (list directories only) and `-L` (specify the number of levels to recurse).

Answer (score 2):

Use tree command under Windows and Linux.

http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0040.html

http://www.centerkey.com/tree/